# sorting strings ending with numbers, by the ending number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of values like:

```
item1, item3, item2, item4, item5, item8, item6, item9, item10, item7, item11
```

When i sort them in javascript using `.sort()` i get the below result:

```
item1, item10, item11, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9
```

I know this is because the items are strings and this what `sort()` is designed to do, but how can i sort them into the following?

```
item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11
```

thanks,

Comment: The easy way would be to do: `item01`, `item02`, etc...

Comment: yes, but it's possible that the items could be in the hundreds, or more, so having a prefix of 0 isn't a full-proof way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define your own `.sort` callback.  In fact you need to do so to sort numbers.  Your case is a bit different, though.

```
.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (+a.replace("item", "")) - (+b.replace("item", ""));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hbs8g/

In case `item` is not consistent, you can get the number part via `.split(/(\d+)/)[1]` assuming that the word part does not contain any numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/Hbs8g/1/

Comment: thanks, nice and simple, wish i'd thought of it :p

Answer (score 0):

Sort takes a comparison function and will sort the list with it.  After sort is called, the list is sorted.

```
z = ["item1", "item3", "item2", "item4", "item5", "item8", "item6", "item9", "item10", "item7", "item11"];    
z.sort(function(a, b) { return parseInt(a.substring(4)) - parseInt(b.substring(4)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following:

```
var a = new Array();
a = ['item1', 'item3', 'item2', 'item4', 'item5', 'item8', 'item6', 'item9', 'item10', 'item7', 'item11'];
var temparray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var substr = (a[i]).substring(4);
    temparray.push(parseInt(substr));
}
temparray.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
 a=temparray;
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, if it is helpful to you

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
a = a.replace("item", "");
b = b.replace("item", "");
if (a > b)
   return 1;
else if (a < b)
   return -1;
else
   return 0;
});
```